# Intercept http calls to include language in header not going through

Tags: angular6

I am trying to pass language preference of user via header. But it is not going through. My method is GET but on the backend I see OPTIONS made successful but the actual GET request I made never gets invoked.

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptAPICalls implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        try {

         var token=currentUserToken(); //get current user token

        // add it if we have one

        if (token) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization','Bearer ' + token) });
        }



        }
catch (e){
    if(e instanceof TypeError){
        //most porbably currentUser is not found
    }
}




        // setting the accept header

        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
        //add language

          var lang=localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'en'; //get the language
        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('language',lang) }); //add to header.


        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have a CORS issue? If your server is on a different domain, you need to configure CORS to allow your client's origin. Otherwise, the browser will block the request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS